# Convert 12 Hour to 24 Hour in JAVA within scope of UTC

Tags: java, time, utc

Please help me convert time from 12 hours to 24 hours format return time should be in UTC in JAVA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you to convert time to 24 Hour

```
public static String convertTo24Hour(String Time) {
    DateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a"); //11:00 pm
    Date d = null;
    try {
        d = f1.parse(Time);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String x = f2.format(d); // "23:00"

    return x;
}
```

Later on you may convert to UTC as per your wish or you may compile code in one function

```
public static String CalculateUTC_Time(String Date, String Time) {
    String X[] = Time.split(":");

    int Hours = Integer.parseInt(X[0]);
    int Minutes = Integer.parseInt(X[1]);

    LocalDate date = new LocalDate(Date);
    LocalTime time = new LocalTime(Hours, Minutes);
    DateTime dt = date.toDateTime(time);

    SimpleDateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    f2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    return (f2.format(dt.toDate()));
}
```